# How to only keep the 12 most significant bits of 16bit PCM audio data?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, wav, 16-bit

I am trying to figure out how to reduce the bit depth of a 16bit wav file to 12bit by truncating the data and dropping the 4 least significant bits.
My best guess is I need to convert the data (which seems to be in signed short integer form) into 16 bit unsigned and shift the bits right by 4, then convert back to short.

But I'm really confused on how to implement that, I am new to both python and DSP concepts, so please bear with me.

```py
import array
import numpy as np
import struct
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound = AudioSegment.from_file("original.wav")

# get raw data from the wav file
samples = sound.get_array_of_samples()
bitSamples = []

# iterate over the data
for i in range (0, len(samples)):
    # convert to 16bit (?)
    sixteen = struct.unpack('H', struct.pack('h', samples[i]))
    # bitwise right shift
    twelve = np.right_shift(sixteen, 4)
    # populate new array
    bitSamples.append(twelve)

shifted_samples_array = array.array(sound.array_type, bitSamples)

new_sound = sound._spawn(shifted_samples_array)
new_sound.export("out-depth.wav", format="wav")
```

Here is what I have tried, but all that seems to do is drastically increase the volume of the audio and make it sound extremely distorted.

What I expect to achieve is basically just reduced dynamic range (ie an intermediate between 8bit and 16bit audio quality).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't just drop 4 bits and expect it to work, your media player must understand that the data uses 12 bits instead of 16 bits per sample.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. How hard would it be to write code that plays the 12bit data?
Also one thing that confuses me then is how do you store and play audio recorded through a 12bit DAC for example?

Comment: `How hard would it be to write code that plays the 12bit data?` Not that hard, you just have to promote it to 16bit data again before playing it. Thats how media players work, they read in whatever format is given and promote (or even demote) it to whatever the sound card wants.